# Find all the integer solutions of $x^2-y^2=a^2+mb^2$

Tags: diophantine-equations

Let $x,y,a,b,m$ be non-zero integers where $m$ is square free. I am trying to find all the integer solutions of $$x^2-y^2=a^2+mb^2$$ I tried to factorize both sides but the righthand side equation is not too friendly. Any hints?

Comment: do you want the hints as answers ?

Comment: Reference, answers, you name it. This problem appears so elementary but yet I cannot figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: If $x=1, y=0, m<0$, finding this part of the solution set is equivalent to Pell's equation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$a^2+mb^2=(zc+mvq)^2+m(zq-vc)^2=(z^2+mv^2)(c^2+mq^2)=(x-y)(x+y)$$

$$x=\frac{1}{2}(c^2+z^2+m(q^2+v^2))$$

$$y=\frac{1}{2}(c^2-z^2+m(q^2-v^2))$$

Comment: Here we have an answer someone can follow, not like some of your other answers